# EntityFramwork - How do I use an existing database and apply migrations while still supporting automatic upgrade?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following.

- An Entity Framework model that maps against a SQLSERVER database. This has production data, but there is no __MigrationHistory table. I need to keep the data.
- A new updated model including new tables, columns etc.

I would like to add migrations so that model changes can be easily managed. I would like to support both `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` by creating all default tables, as well as being able to apply migration #2 patches on the current data structure.

I have followed Microsofts tutorial "*Code First Migrations with an existing database*" but this gives me the problem of the initial `-ignoreChanges` resulting in not being able to create the model from scratch. I need to be able to both recreate it as well as add migrations on the existing database without migration history. This since the `-ignoreChanges` on the initial migration gives me an empty `up()`, and the second migration script will only contain code for the patched tables/columns. If I don't ignore changes then the framework will try to create tables that already exist.

I was considering to not ignore changes on the initial migration and then do some kind of `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"` for all existing tables, but that seems impossible.

I bet I'm missing something right out in the open. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested but it should do:

- use old model to create a _MigrationHistory table
- copy/paste (select/insert or any etl method) the _MigrationHistory in the production database
- update the model to new one
- create a new migration
- push the migration to the db.

DO ALL THIS FIRST IN A TEST ENVIRONMENT !